# Deal with blank background layout for RecognizerIntent

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-widget, android-manifest, voice-recognition

i am newbie in to android studio and java. i am making an app using speech recognition. The app is working fine but i decided to look into this issue.

[STT dialog screen after button is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GteI8.png)

[blank background layout if user pressed back or touch outside the STT dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn2Yu.png)

If user said something, the activity works ok. But if the user pressed back or touch outside the dialog. A blank layout is shown which i want to avoid.

this STT activity will be called via widget and the app activity.

STT activity in manifests

```
    <activity
        android:name=".RecordActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_record"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

launch STT via Widget

```
        Intent popUpIntent = new Intent(context, RecordActivity.class);
        popUpIntent.setAction("com.XXX.XXX.FROM_WIDGET");
        popUpIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        popUpIntent.putExtra("fileName", recordFile.getAbsolutePath());
        context.startActivity(popUpIntent);
```

launch STT via Activity

```
        Intent popUpIntent = new Intent(this, RecordActivity.class);
        popUpIntent.putExtra("fileName", recordFile.getAbsolutePath());
        startActivityForResult(popUpIntent , START_RECORD);
```

STT activity:

```
public class RecordActivity extends Activity  implements RecognitionListener {

//
private static final int REQUEST_SPEECH_TO_TEXT = 1;

private String fileName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    promptSpeechInput();
    // Read Filename
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    fileName = intent.getStringExtra("fileName");
}

public void onSubmit(View view) {
    finish();
}

/**
 * Receiving speech input
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_SPEECH_TO_TEXT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                // the resulting text is in the getExtras:
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                ArrayList<String> matches = bundle.getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                // Default 
                contentText = matches.get(0);
                Uri audioUri = data.getData();
                ...
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
                finish();
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}

private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    voiceIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.DICTATION_MODE", true);       // can listen for a long time
    voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 10000);
    voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 5000);
    voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 5000);
    voiceIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO_FORMAT", "audio/AMR");
    voiceIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO", true);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(voiceIntent, REQUEST_SPEECH_TO_TEXT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.record_audio_denied),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {

}

@Override
public void onError(int error) {

}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {

}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

}

@Override
public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

}
```

}

In this activity, please forgive me in not deleting those RecognitionListener methods, because i was going to embed those methods myself instead of using RecognizerIntent in this activity.

Actually, i work around with Theme.NoDisplay in manifests that the beep sound works but STT dialog does not show up until it catches error (i.e. no sounds)

STT part in manifests

```
    <activity
        android:name=".RecordActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_record"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
```

In my mind, there are few possible solutions:

1) maybe some intent.setAction("") or intent.setFlags() will help - mostly perferable

2) "@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" might actually work - preferable

3) add finish() to touch action and OnBackpressed in RecognizerIntent - less preferable

4) implement RecognitionListener instead - i will go this way if none of above works.

5) use STT as service in background - required a bit of more work

===============================================================================

OK, thank you for pointing out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones) which is same as my option (4) and then i have some issue getting the audio data by making my own RecognitionListener...(sorry for not mentioning I need the text and audio output from RecognizerIntent before...problem after a problem), i have updated my Activity code with few lines getting text and audio...

seem to me, in order to get the audio data, this approach lacks of obvious resource. but from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339519/how-to-build-bufferreceived-to-capture-voice-using-recognizerintent) and i am looking at some code example,

> RecognitionService.Callback says about bufferReceived

and RecognitionService.Callback is what i am trying to understand now.

but back to this question, i wonder if anyone could suggest an easier way for my issue, because if there is not, i may come up with option 6.

6) put a fancy custom layout to replace the blank layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use speech recognition without the annoying dialog in android phones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones)

Comment: thank you for pointing out this duplicate. i have updated my code since i need both text and audio output from RecognizerIntent. but many said onBufferReceived does not work in RecognitionListener. do you have any idea?