# Can you retrieve the voice recording from Speech Recognition plaforms like Amazon Alexa or Google Assistant?

Tags: actions-on-google, alexa-skills-kit, voice-recognition

Is there any way to get the actual recorded audio input from a Google Assistant or Amazon Alexa device to use in my own API backend?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16340756/8383428) regarding the Android Speech Recognition API mentions that it's not really possible to get the audio recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the platform provides a developer with the user transcription, it does not provide the underlying audio that generated the query.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Does your answer stem from a particular point in the documentation of one of the services?

Comment: It's primarily based on personal experience with the platforms